# Digital Projector color features?

Tags: colors, color-space, projector

My question is regarding color-based features of digital multimedia projectors. Since the recent versions are using LED technologies, I was wondering if there is any special feature/restriction when the projectors are showing a specific colors. As an example, is there any efficiency or quality factor difference when they are projecting a white screen vs showing a black screen? Maybe in terms of energy, or something? Or there is no difference, and the logic doesn't care about the color context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an article](http://www.madronadigital.com/Library/ProjectorDemystified.html) talking about the different projectors' technologies: As usual when comparing LED versus incandescent, advantages of the former are less power consumption, longer life and increased robustness. Also, LEDs can produce a much larger [colour gamut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut), which leads to a higher perceived contrast. No conclusive statement can be made about the produced quality in terms of sharpness as it depends on the particular model.